How do I redirect all non-existant files in a subdirectory to the main page?
I have the following structure:
-files
--toppage
--existing-file
--second-file

Now imagine someone goes to example.com/files/no-file
I want them to redirect to example.com/files/toppage
But when someone goes to example.com/files/existing-file they still need to be able to go to existing-file.
For several reasons I can not move any of the files. Is there a way to redirect everything in the subfolder that goes to a non-existing url to the toppage?
I also can't just redirect all 404 requests to the toppage because there is other subdirectories with different behavior.
I've tried several htaccess solutions, but I can't get it to work for ONLY non-existant files.
This is the final code I had:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdir/toppage.php [L]


Rewriting only when a file doesn't exist

Take a look at the flag -f and -d that are supported by the RewriteCond directive. Consult the official documentation, it is, as typical for OpenSource software, of excellent quality and comes with realistic examples.
